# To improve performance, is it better to run as few commands as possible in a query or to process the least amount of data?

Tags: excel, performance, query-optimization, powerquery

I’ve adopted the practice of “trimming” unneeded data from a query as I go. For instance, as soon as I don’t need columns in a query I add a command to delete them. If later I don’t need a set of rows, I filter them out. This adds more steps to my query, but my thinking is that at every step I’m using the least amount of data necessary and therefore I’m making my query more efficient. However, is that really the case?

From other posts, I too find power query M queries getting bogged down at each and every command, so now I’m thinking should I just wait until the end to delete superfluous data or does it make any difference?